# Even though content-disposition has proper file name , but local downloaded file has different name

Tags: ajax, spring, user-interface, web, content-disposition

From UI to backend getting a call of type xhr, and from the backend sending the file, with one important response header as below

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=abc_0714_844G_4_2023Jul14_045451.csv
```

but when we check the file name which is downloaded to local, we see different file name. why this happening?

our backend java code in spring rest controller.

```
File file = reportGeneratorService.generateReport(migrationId, orgId);

return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName())
            .contentLength(file.length())
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(CSV_FILE_CONTENT_TYPE))
            .body(new FileSystemResource(file));
```

We tried to research, but nothing useful found related to this